# Why does uploading a media file a second time restore older version?

Tags: media, revisions

Sometimes I wish to update a media file, but when I `Delete Permanently` from the library, and then upload the same file a second time, instead of getting the revised version, I instead recover the older deleted version.

For now, I work around by changing the file name slightly to create a new file instead of uploading using the name of the old deleted file.

How can I revise a media file in my library with a new version created outside of WordPress?

I'm using WordPress v4.0. I tried switching the theme back to the default theme `Twenty Thirteen` v1.3 while also disabling all my plug-ins, but the issue persists. I did notice that it worked the first time, so perhaps the issue only arises when you upload a second time on the same day and if you wait till the next day the issue goes away? Same behavior the next day, worked the first time, but not subsequently.

I tried clearing my browser cache and it did not help, I also tried a different browser, and it too saw the old file, so this does not appear to be a browser issue.

Comment: Are you using some plugin to upload media files? And have you tried it with the default theme and all plugins turned off? Also, WP does _not_ create files (aside from resized images), but add DB entries to wrap media data into `attachment` post type entities.

Comment: Switch back to one of the default themes, turn plugins off. Does the problem persist?

Comment: Please suggest how to improve this downvoted question.

Comment: Read [ask] as a starter. The [help] provides guidance as well. Also answer my questions - with an **[edit]** to the question.

Comment: It's not a WP issue - it's your browser showing the cached version of the file. Clear your cache to see that the new version has indeed uploaded.

Comment: @bonger Clearing the cache did not fix, nor did trying a different browser to view after update of file.

Comment: Actually... I have seen this type of behavior earlier. As far as I can remember, I did double check with cleared cache. I will see if I can reproduce this issue. If this is an issue, I guess it is related to the file not being removed properly but its meta data is. And then readded whenever reuploaded... although all of this is a guess.